# getAllNetworkInfo detect wifi or mobile connection, but never both

Tags: android

I have a function which check network connections using:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
```

but, as soon the Wifi network is connected, the mobile network is given as DISCONNECTED

How could I know if both networks are connected?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: do you need only network connectivity or need to fetch every connected network details?

Comment: I need to inform the user about mobile & wifi connections.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
NetworkInfo mobileNet = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
if(netInfo!=null){
  if(mobileNet.isConnected()){
    System.out.println("Mobile Network is connected");

  }
  if(wifi.isConnected()){
    System.out.println("Wi-fi Network is connected");
  }

}
```

Comment: No sorry, it's what I've already used but without success... thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How could I know if both networks are connected?

You can create for sure method that will check for both types e.q.

```
if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
   // do your stuff
}
if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

But in Android OS, if Wifi and Mobile network is available (and you can connect to), OS will choose Wifi by default so it'll use Wifi as active network connection.

Comment: No sorry, it's what I've already used but without success... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android device can have only one connection!  (WiFi or Mobile)

1. If WiFi is available - system will try to connect to it
2. If WiFi is not available and Mobile is turned on - system will try to connect to Mobile
3. When system is connected to WiFi - You cant' be shure that Mobile will work until you try to connect.
4. Same for Moble

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But how the system is able to display both icons on the top of the smartphone?

Comment: What device are you using? Version of Android? Is your both icons showing data transmission in one time (simultaneously) or they are  only showing that both networks turned on ?

Comment: Hi Andrew and sorry for my late.
I use a Wiko Cink Five with Android 4.1.2, but the visibility of the icons is the same wathever the device.

Comment: I've tested my devices, and from debug i can see that other connection are not available when one is turned on. You can't have different connections in one time.